# Obtener los datos de una columna de las filas que contengan alguna celda vacía - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataset donde algunas de las filas tienen por algún extraño motivo celdas en blanco en algunas de sus columnas. Por este motivo debo volver a calcular dichas filas para que así tenga su información al completo.

He sido capaz de hallar las filas con celdas vacías.

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame

df = read_csv('results.csv')

# Obtengo que filas tienen celdas vacías en alguna columna
nan_rows = df[df.isnull().any(1)]
rows = nan_rows.isnull()
print(rows)
```

He incluso se que columnas son las "problemáticas".

```
# Obtengo las columnas con celdas vacías
cols = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
print(cols)
```

Pero lo que me gustaría es de las filas que hay valores vacíos, obtener el valor de su columna "Code" (esta nunca está vacía). Así puedo acudir a los datos originales con este código y recalcular de nuevo los valores perdidos.

Intento conseguirlo con el primer bloque de código que he mostrado, pero me devuelve `True/False` para definir si la celda esta vacía o no y en consecuencia no puedo seleccionar el dato que yo quiero.

También he conseguido sacar los índices de las `rows` empleando `ind = rows.index.values`, pero me da la sensación que me estoy complicando, pues `Pandas` suele ofrecer soluciones "directas" a este tipo de problemáticas, y es lo que me gustaría aprender.

Pruebo cosas de este estilo, pero me da error...

`pp = df['Code'].isnull().any(1)`

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

@Lleims, por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es que te gustaría obtener la columna "Code" en donde otras columnas hay valores en blanco.

Si te entendí bien, no estás lejos de lo que necesitas.

```python
def solution(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Filtra la DataFrame en donde haya valores que faltan "na" y luego da como
    resultado la columna "Code"

    Parametros
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame

    Returns
    -------
    pd.Series
    """
    return df.loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)]["Code"]
```

Al crear una función puedes pasarle esta función a tu DataFrame o cualquier DataFrame que tenga estas mismas condiciones.

Puedes usar la función como se usa tradicionalmente en Python:

```py
solution(df)
```

O puedes pasarla usando la funcion `pd.DataFrame.pipe`. Pipe da muchas ventajas ya que puedes seguir aplicando otras funciones o transformaciones.

```py
df.pipe(solution)
```